# Cocoapods: An unexpected version directory `General` was encountered

Tags: cocoapods

> I have created private cocoa pods and successfully created pod. But while  I m installing the pod file in project but facing issue like "An unexpected version directory General was encountered.
>
> I m following same structure for pod specification as per
>   https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html
>
> Also, General folder is available and inside this folder classes is
>   there.

**AppKit.podspec**

https://gist.github.com/nikunjazilen/d2fc5b3ee688aab91094a7b0569626b2

**Podfile**

https://gist.github.com/nikunjazilen/2f4fa8db6a5b6206edd07814cc421bf6

**Folder Structure:**

> Spec -> AppKit -> 2.0.5 -> AppKit.podspec

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your podfile and podspec file (the part you added doesn't contains the spec.version)?

Comment: @MarcoPace. I have added podspec and podfile. Can you please check it and let me know if any issue is there or not?